# How can I create a regex that matches a string contains a word from one list AND does not contains word from another list?

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

How can I create a regex that matches a string contains a word from one list AND does not contains word from another list?

I want to create a regex that match a string containing any of the following words (fox,cat) and does not contain (red,black).

Ex:

> The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog --- match
>
> The quick red fox jumps over the lazy dog ----  no match
>
> The quick brown lion jumps over the lazy cat---- match
>
> The quick black cat jumps over the lazy dog ---- no match

Is it possible with Regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Regex: `^(?:(?!(red|black)).)*(?:fox|cat)(?:(?!(red|black)).)*$`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/blxZmW/2)

Explanation:

```
    Non-capturing group (?:(?!(red|black)).)* - Confirms red or black is not present before fox or cat
        Negative Lookahead (?!(red|black)) - Assert that the Regex below does not match
            1st Capturing Group (red|black)
                1st Alternative red - red matches the characters red literally (case sensitive)
                2nd Alternative black - black matches the characters black literally (case sensitive)
        . matches any character (except for line terminators)

    Non-capturing group (?:fox|cat) - confirms fox or cat is present
        1st Alternative fox - fox matches the characters fox literally (case sensitive)
        2nd Alternative cat - cat matches the characters cat literally (case sensitive)

Non-capturing group (?:(?!(red|black)).)* - Confirms red or black is not present after fox or cat
        Negative Lookahead (?!(red|black)) - Assert that the Regex below does not match
            1st Capturing Group (red|black)
                1st Alternative red - red matches the characters red literally (case sensitive)
                2nd Alternative black - black matches the characters black literally (case sensitive)
        . matches any character (except for line terminators)
```

Comment: red and black can be anywhere in the string for ex The quick  fox jumps over the lazy dog black -- > this should not be matched